# How to use a string as a column name in redshift Postgresql (Dynamic conversion of string to column name)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, dynamic-sql

I have a table with just 1 record as below

```
*--------------*
*  columns     *
*--------------*
*id,name,city  *
*--------------*
```

My goal is to run the following query  :

```
SELECT id,name,city
FROM schema.table;
```

How do I acheive this?

Comment: You need to construct the query in your application and then pass it in.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this in SQL workbench

Comment: what is the output you want?

Comment: My variables of interest are stored in a table field as string (in my example : "id,name,city"). I want to select these columns (id,name,city) from another table.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to solve this with a simple sql statement, but might be possible to create and execute an dynamic sql statement by using a stored procedure - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-result-set.html